# Angular 8: Reactive form converts ObjectID to string when updating

Tags: angular, mongodb, loopback

I have an update form where i have a reference id with type ObjectID. How do i keep the ObjectID when updating from changing to string? I tried to use bson package to convert it back and the results shows this when i console.log my form.value:

`id: ObjectId {id: Uint8Array(12)}`

which basically was what i actually intended. but when i check the document in mongo compass it was still inserted as string.

is there a way to fix this? maybe other solution perhaps?

FYI Im using loopback as my backend and used the auto generated CRUD controller

update with code below:

updateform.ts

```
//create formcontrol    
this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
                field1: this._formBuilder.array([
                ])

//patch value
 setValue() {
        let control = this.form.get('field1') as FormArray;
            this.data$.field1.forEach(x => {
                control.push(this._formBuilder.group({
                    id: new ObjectID(x.id),
                    name: x.name
                }))
        })
    }
```

updateform.html

```
<div formArrayName="field1"
   *ngFor="let field of form.get('field1')['controls']; let i = index;">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <mat-form-field>
           <input matInput placeholder="Ref. ID" formControlName="id">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: `"strictObjectIDCoercion": true` set this in model definition json file